# Why can't I type my password after using a sudo command?

Tags: 14.04, password, sudo

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

When I go to use a sudo command, it asks for my password.
When I go to type my password, it doesn't let me type a password.

If anyone could possibly help, I would really appreciate it

Comment: It is letting you, it just won't appear, for security. Try typing then press enter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It lets you type the password, it just doesn't show it to you. Type the correct password and press enter. You should be able to go.

Comment: is there a way i can make it show up?

Comment: I don't think so but you can definitely see asterisks for characters just like on websites. Follow the steps on this answer to do this: http://superuser.com/a/420818/141293

Comment: You don't want it to show, that is a security flaw.

Comment: thanks for all the help guys. ive done the sudo visudo thingy and i get stars now, for me thats good because i get forgetful

Comment: i dont care if its a security floor as i am the only user, and i have a bios password thingy set up to actually get into the os

Comment: ive finally downloaded the arduino ide, sigh