# I can't see the password when I enter it in Terminal wth the command "su"

Tags: 14.04, sudo, gnome-terminal

I'm trying to install Java, but it requires the "su" command.
When I enter my password, the password field remains blank.
I try to enter my password, but it remains blank. I press enter, just in case in the sight chance it's techincally entered and I can't see it.
It gives me an Authentication Failed message and it makes me enter my password again. Finally, I just exit the terminal. I've read [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/513814/why-cant-i-type-my-password-after-using-a-sudo-command?newreg=0069b371cc924e16b9db34275280689d)
and did not answer my question. My instructions are [here.](https://java.com/en/download/help/linux_x64rpm_install.xml)And maybe I'm using the wrong version of Java, so if that is, please point me to the correct version. Here's my system stats:

I'm using terminal, on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Also, I installed Ubuntu about 4 hours ago, so I'm new.

Any help would be greatly appricated.

Thanks in advance,
Ryan

Comment: `su` (without an explicit username) would require the password to the `root` account - which is normally disabled on Ubuntu. I'd suggest modifying the instructions so that you use `sudo` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but it requires the "su" command

No it does not. It needs "sudo".

> but it remains blank

What did you expect? Inputting passwords is always going to be hidden so nobody behind you can see what you insert.

---

Regarding the link in your question: please do NOT use installers for operating systems other than Ubuntu (or Debian). Installers for Redhat or SUSE do NOT WORK on Ubuntu.

Regarding installing Java: before the command you are suppose to use to install java you put the command `sudo` and when asked for a password you insert the password for your user. If you have more than 1 user make sure you use the admin account; by default that is the user Ubuntu was installed with unless you changed it afterwards.

---

The default repositories have a JDK. Install can be done with:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install default-jdk
```

And for latest version from oracle you could use [this how-to](https://thishosting.rocks/install-java-ubuntu/).

Comment: What java installer am I to use, then? And also, when my password is entered, it's not in dots or asterisks, it's just invisible and as good as a blank password.

Comment: Passwords are not echoed back to the terminal, so shoulder-surfers can't get the length. While it looks like a blank password, it is NOT. It's what you typed.